# In Silverlight 3 can every cell of the datagrid be editable concurrently?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid

In an SL3 datagrid, is it possible to have every cell of the grid editable?

I need to create a UI that's similar to an Excel worksheet. Upon a button click, the entire collection of objects would be submitted as opposed a single object or cell.

Is this even possible, and if so how would I go about achieving it?

Thanks.

Comment: This is certainly achievable. Have you looked at silverlight.net site for any example? I don't have code with me but I am sure it is certainly possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the reason why this question has sat here 4 hours with no answer is that we all asking ourselves "Have I missed the problem here?".

First of all you can't actually "edit every cell concurrently", after all when you hit a key on the keyboard only one control is going accept that is input, the one with the focus.

"Excel worksheet" behaviour is exactly what you get from DataGrid if you let it automatically generate the cells.

So this question is really about the object you assign to the `ItemsSource` property. You really need to tell us about what you are using to store the data.

The truth is your requirement is quite easy to deliver especially if you include WCF RIA services.  Ulitmately you get a "Data Context" which you can edit in various ways and then submit changes at whatever point makes sense for your application.

Comment: Ah, ok. Obviously I've misunderstood the behaviour of a datagrid. 

Thinking about it, maybe my problem is more to do with the appearence of the grid, i.e. make it look like that each cell is in an editable state + single-click to start editing. I'll search for q&a based on this.

Thanks for your help.